# Where is the `footer` class in the Bootstrap css files?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am brand new to coding, I understand HTML and CSS classes and am now trying to use Bootstrap.

I for the life of me can not find the `footer` class in any of the bootstrap css files (such as bootstrap.css)

Likewise, I also can't find the class for `jumbotron` either.  Am I missing something here? I would like to edit their appearances.

Thank you! This is my first stackoverflow question, so sorry if the formatting isn't great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find

> footer and
> jumbotron

classes in bootstrap 4, but in bootstrap 5 they have dropped these component classes.

you can check the other removed class on the official bootstrap 5 docs website

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/

Comment: and in bootstrap 4 also there is no use of footer class as it only contains the property display: block

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no class named `footer` in BootStrap 5. And if there is, I can not find any reason for why it exist: The footer is the "unique" element in the whole document, why would we create a class named "footer"
Would you please provide your code context?
Closest class I can found is just `page-footer` in BootStrap document
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/navigation/footer/

Comment: It appears that `footer` was in BootStrap 4, but removed from BS5, I was reading a guide that was using BS4 and assumed BS5 would have similar classes.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

BootStrap 4 has classes such as `footer` and `jumbotron` but appear to have been removed in BootStrap 5.